# Logging Exception using AOP in .netcore web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a web API project and want to use a logger to log all my controller actions to a file.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult GetAllDocumentTempates()
    {
        try
        {
            var document = _doumentTemplate.GetLiteDocumentReportTemplates().ToList();
            var result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LiteDocumentReportTemplateViewModel>>(document);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = string.Format("{0}; Inner Ex: {1};  Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(string.Format("From frmDelivery.ConditionallyPrint():{0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

`This is my ExceptionLoggingService.cs:`
This is the service that handles all the errors and logging to files for me

```
public class ExceptionLoggingService: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // </ Singleton code
    // private fields
    private readonly FileStream _fileStream;
    private readonly StreamWriter _streamWriter;
    private static ExceptionLoggingService _instance;
    // public property
    public static ExceptionLoggingService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new ExceptionLoggingService());
        }
    }
    //private constructor
    private ExceptionLoggingService()
    {
        _fileStream = File.OpenWrite(GetExecutionFolder() + "\\EasyAsFallingOffA.log");
        _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileStream);
    }
    // <!-- Singleton code

    public void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        if (!HHSConsts.Logging) return;
        StringBuilder formattedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        formattedMessage.AppendLine("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        formattedMessage.AppendLine("Message: " + message);
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(formattedMessage.ToString());
        _streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    private string GetExecutionFolder()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    }
}
```

This is my `EasyAsFallingOffA.log` file output

> Date: 6/23/2018 12:02:24 PM
> Message: From frmDelivery.ConditionallyPrint(): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.; Inner Ex: Stack Trace:    at ProcessFlowManager.Domain.Helpers.ModelFactory.Create(CalendarActivity cal) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.Domain\Helpers\ModelFactory.cs: line 1170
> at ProcessFlowManager.Infrastructure.LogicImplementations.EfCalendarActivities.GetCalendarActivity(Int32 id) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.Infrastructure\LogicImplementations\EfCalendarActivities.cs:line 54
> at ProcessFlowManager.API.Controllers.CalendarController.GetAllGeneratedDcument(Int32 id) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.API\Controllers\CalendarController.cs:line 79

Using Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP), the code above can be restructured to avoid repetition. Instead of using try-catch statements for each piece of code, AOP can be used to create an aspect which can handle the exception handling for all the code. This aspect can be called once in the controller so that it encompasses all the pieces of code. This will not only save the time required for writing try-catch statements for each piece of code but also make the code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I need to implement this using Aspect Oriented Programming but have tried everything but all to no avail and i don't want to use third party

Comment: I need some advice on this please and nobody should introduce third parties because its not free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of shuffling the internet trying to get answer to my question i have successfully logged all my exception without using third parties libraries like PostSharp, Log4File, Spring etc.
Using

> ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter

I was able to solve this and log all my exception for enterprise project with the following code

```
public class LatestErrorHandler : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    private const string FILE_NAME = "Exception.log";
    private const string TRACE_FILE = "TraceLog.log";
    public Type _exceptionType;
    FileStream _fileStream;
    StreamWriter _streamWriter;
    IHostingEnvironment host;
    public LatestErrorHandler(Type exceptionType)
    {
       // _fileStream = File.OpenWrite(host.ContentRootPath + "\\wale.log");
        //_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileStream);
        //_fileStream.Close();
        _exceptionType = exceptionType;
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        using (FileStream fs=new FileStream(TRACE_FILE, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter rite=new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.Response==null)
                {
                    string con = "No log";
                    rite.Write(con);
                }
                else
                {
                    Controller exValue = (Controller)context.Controller;
                    ControllerContext control = (ControllerContext)exValue.ControllerContext;
                    ///HttpMethodActionConstraint http = (HttpMethodActionConstraint)control.ActionDescriptor.ActionConstraints.;

                    rite.Write(
                                 "  Date Exception Occurred" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                                 "  Route " 
                                 +control.RouteData.DataTokens.Values
                                 +context.RouteData.Routers
                                 //+control.ActionDescriptor.ActionConstraints+ ":"+ http.HttpMethods
                                 + context.RouteData.Values.Keys
                                 + control.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
                                 +context.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues.Values+
                                 "  Parameter"
                                 + context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters 
                                 +context.ActionDescriptor.Properties+
                                 "  Controller" 
                                 + control.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName

                                           );
                }
            }
        }


    }





    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var cont= context.Exception;
        //var contInner = context.Exception.InnerException;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter rite = new BinaryWriter(fs))
          {
                // context.Result actionResult = new context.Result();

                if (context.HttpContext.Response == null)
                {
                    string con = "no errroer  ";
                    rite.Write(con);
                }
                else
                {

                    rite.Write(
                        "Date Exception Occurred" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                        " Exceptions" + "Message: " + cont.Message +
                        " InnerException" + cont.InnerException +
                        " StackTrace" + cont.StackTrace+
                        "Response" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
                    );




                }

            }

        }

    }






    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        var cont = context.Exception;
        //var contInner = context.Exception.InnerException;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter rite=new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                // context.Result actionResult = new context.Result();
               var type =  context.Result.GetType().Name;   //context.Result

                if(type == "BadRequestObjectResult" )
                {

                    BadRequestObjectResult cont2 = (BadRequestObjectResult)context.Result;


                    Exception exValue = (Exception) cont2.Value;
                    if (exValue.InnerException==null)
                    {
                        rite.Write(
                              "\n  Date Exception Occurred  " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                              "\n  Exceptions" + "Message: " + cont2.Value +
                             // "\n  InnerException  " + exValue.InnerException +
                              "\n  Message    " + exValue.Message +
                              "\n  StackTrace  " + exValue.StackTrace
                       //"Response" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
                       );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rite.Write(
                               "\n  Date Exception Occurred  " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                               "\n  Exceptions" + "Message: " + cont2.Value +
                               "\n  InnerException  " + exValue.InnerException +
                               "\n  Message    " + exValue.Message +
                               "\n  StackTrace  " + exValue.StackTrace
                        //"Response" + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
                        );
                    }


                }






                else
                {
                    // log details without error.





                }

            }

        }

    }



}
```

with this class i used Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP) to successfully log all my exception to file in all my controller.

```
 [LatestErrorHandler(typeof(ExceptionContext))]
//[CustomLoggingAttirbute]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Calendar")]
public class CalendarController : Controller
{
      ICalendarActivities calendarActivities;

    IHostingEnvironment IHostingEnvironment;

    string projectFolder = "";
    string fileRootPath = "";

    // private string projectRootFolder;
    public CalendarController(ICalendarActivities _calendarActivities)
    {
        calendarActivities = _calendarActivities;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]

    public IActionResult GetAllCalenderReportList()
    {
        try
        {
            var calendars = calendarActivities.GetCalendarActivities();
            var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LiteCalendarViewModel>>(calendars);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            //string msginnerexandstacktrace = string.Format("{0}; inner ex: {1};  stack trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
            //ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(string.Format("from frmdelivery.conditionallyprint():{0}", msginnerexandstacktrace));
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
```

This is my output

> Date Exception Occurred  7/2/2018 5:13:18 PM
>     ExceptionsMessage: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ProcessFlowManager.Domain.Helpers.ModelFactory.Create(CalendarActivity cal) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.Domain\Helpers\ModelFactory.cs:line 1170
>      at ProcessFlowManager.Infrastructure.LogicImplementations.EfCalendarActivities.GetCalendarActivity(Int32 id) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.Infrastructure\LogicImplementations\EfCalendarActivities.cs:line 48
>      at ProcessFlowManager.API.Controllers.CalendarController.GetAllGeneratedDcument(Int32 id) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.API\Controllers\CalendarController.cs:line 83
>     InnerException
>     Message    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     StackTrace     at ProcessFlowManager.Domain.Helpers.ModelFactory.Create(CalendarActivity cal) in C:\Users\BABATUNDE\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\pcm-netcore\ProcessFlowManager.Domain\Helpers\ModelFactory.cs:line 1170

Comment: In my case, this approach works perfectly when I don't treat the exception at all. If I have a try-catch block inside the method, then the Error handler specified via attribute does not seem to react.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to get started :
[Aspect Oriented Programming Using C# and PostSharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator)

And Or This:
[Injecting Behaviors Before and After Method Execution](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator)

First Level :

1) Add Class your project With Named LoggingAspect

2) inheritance of OnMethodBoundaryAspect

3)so Implementation OnEntry,OnSuccess,OnExit,OnException

Like below Code:

```
    [PSerializable]
   public class LoggingAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
   {

     public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} method has been entered.", args.Method.Name);
     }

     public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("The {0} method executed successfully.", args.Method.Name);
     }

     public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} method has exited.", args.Method.Name);
     }     

     public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown in {0}.", args.Method.Name);
     }

    }

  static class Program
  {
      [LoggingAspect]
      static void Main()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello, world.");
      }
   }
```

OutPut :

```
     The Main method has been entered.
     Hello, world.
     The Main method executed successfully.
     The Main method has exited.
```

Comment: will this add the log to file

Comment: Sorry but this is not helpful i said i don't want to use third party for AOP implementation @Ali Tooshmalani